# Remove down arrow on html select list for blackberry?

Tags: css, forms, blackberry

I know styling form elements with CSS is always a bit tricky, but is there a way to remove the down arrow from a select list for Blackberrys? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to take care of everything:

```
-moz-appearance: checkbox-container;
-webkit-appearance: button;
appearance: button;
```

Comment: Does RIM/Blackberry implement those vendor-prefixes? (I'm genuinely curious, not assaying that they don't.)

Comment: Im not sure if its using one of the prefixes or the non prefixed version.

Comment: BlackBerry got a webkit browser with OS6.  Before that, it was their own browser implementation.  You need to check both.